# Kivy - Complex forms with vector

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I'm trying to create with vector the figure below in Kivy, however I'm not able to create it. I only find instructions for basic shapes.

[image]

Could someone help me with this problem or clarify to me if it is possible to create more complex forms in Kivy?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can draw that shape with a [line](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.graphics.html#kivy.graphics.Line) on a widget's canvas:

> Parameters:
>
> points: List of points in the format (x1, y1, x2, y2…)

Or if you want it filled use a [mesh](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.graphics.vertex_instructions.html#kivy.graphics.vertex_instructions.Mesh), you can give it a custom texture afterwards.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Is it possible to fill in color a shape created by dots forming lines?

Comment: I don't think so... If your shape is not complex consider just making a few colored rectangles. You can also make your image in another module like PIL and convert it to a kivy Image you can use.